# iOS 9 beta 4 not move all items from the view frame

Tags: ios, xcode, view, frame, move

I have this code to move the view when keyboard appears:

```
const int movementDistance = -160; // tweak as needed
const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed

int movement = (up ? movementDistance : -movementDistance);

[UIView beginAnimations: @"animateTextField" context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This code works for iOS7 & iOS8 but with iOS9 doesn't move all items in the view, only a few of them.

(the constrains are the same)

Someone with the same problem?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I have a similar problem. No solution yet. Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632207/cant-move-keyboard-view-ios9-swift and https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout/issues/82#issuecomment-141334708